# Does the iOS SDK come with a library of artwork/icons?

Tags: ios, artwork

For example, sort of like visual studio does? Perhaps for gestures like pinch/swipe/etc?

Comment: More specific examples of what you're looking for would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

No. You can use [pre-defined icons for buttons](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012857-UIView-SW1), but that's about it.

(You may need to scroll down a screen from the linked position)